# Possible to add multiple columns together and Alias in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, null

I'm pretty green with SQL writing in general. What I am attempting to do is return a singular value from a SELECT query with multiple JOINS and WHERE Criteria.

EX: The following returns the 3 values in question I am after:

```
SELECT TBL5.FIELD1, TBL5.FIELD2, TBL5.FIELD3 
FROM TBL1 PA
JOIN TBL2 PH ON PH.PAID = PA.PAID
JOIN TBL3 CM ON CM.CMID = PA.ECMID
JOIN TBL4 HD ON CM.SURID = HD.PHID
JOIN TBL5 PD ON PD.PHID = HD.PHID
WHERE PH.PSID = 1234
AND PA.PAID = 10039528
AND NVL(PA.ECMID,0) > 0
AND CM.CMTV = 'EECR'
AND PD.MAID = 939252
```

What I want to do is return the value of all three columns TBL5.FIELD1, TBL5.FIELD2, TBL5.FIELD3 as (1) aliased field. With the record I am currently working at retrieving, the last 2 fields are null and the first field returns -32.47. But when I do the below, all I get returned is [null] instead of the expected (-32.47 + null + null) = (-32.47)?

```
SELECT (TBL5.FIELD1 + TBL5.FIELD2 + TBL5.FIELD3) AS TOTAL_REFUND
FROM TBL1 PA
JOIN TBL2 PH ON PH.PAID = PA.PAID
JOIN TBL3 CM ON CM.CMID = PA.ECMID
JOIN TBL4 HD ON CM.SURID = HD.PHID
JOIN TBL5 PD ON PD.PHID = HD.PHID
WHERE PH.PSID = 1234
AND PA.PAID = 10039528
AND NVL(PA.ECMID,0) > 0
AND CM.CMTV = 'EECR'
AND PD.MAID = 939252
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`null` is not a value, it's a lack thereof. You could think of it as an "unknown" value. So when adding any real value to an unknown value, the result would be unknown - or, in database terms, `null`. If you want to treat it as a zero, you'd have to do so explicitly, e.g., by using the [`coalesce`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions033.htm) function:

```
SELECT (COALESCE(TBL5.FIELD1,0) + 
        COALESCE(TBL5.FIELD2,0) + 
        COALESCE(TBL5.FIELD3,0)) AS TOTAL_REFUND
FROM TBL1 PA
JOIN TBL2 PH ON PH.PAID = PA.PAID
JOIN TBL3 CM ON CM.CMID = PA.ECMID
JOIN TBL4 HD ON CM.SURID = HD.PHID
JOIN TBL5 PD ON PD.PHID = HD.PHID
WHERE PH.PSID = 1234
AND PA.PAID = 10039528
AND NVL(PA.ECMID,0) > 0
AND CM.CMTV = 'EECR'
AND PD.MAID = 939252
```

Comment: Thanks! That does make sense. I'll read up on `NVL/COALESCE()` and take a look.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is noted [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements005.htm)

> Any arithmetic expression containing a null always evaluates to null. For example, null added to 10 is null. In fact, all operators (except concatenation) return null when given a null operand.

So `-32.47 + null + null` will always be null. As @Mureinik has shown, you need to provide a default value to replace the nulls, which you can do with the standard [`coalesce()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions030.htm), or the [`nvl()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions119.htm):

```
SELECT NVL(TBL5.FIELD1,0) + NVL(TBL5.FIELD2,0)
  + NVL(TBL5.FIELD3,0) AS TOTAL_REFUND
...
```

They do the same thing in this case, but coalesce is more flexible.